# Can we find $E(XY)$ if given $E(X), E(Y), E(X^2), E(Y^2)$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables with 
$E(X)=a, E(Y)=b, E(X^2)=c, E(Y^2)=d$. $X$ and $Y$ not necessary to independent.
I have problem, I can't find E(XY) when given $E(X), E(Y), E(X^2), E(Y^2)$.
I try to find using
$$E((X+Y)^2)=E(X^2)+2E(XY)+E(Y^2),$$
But I confused to find $E((X+Y)^2)$. So can we find E(XY) if only given  $E(X), E(Y), E(X^2), E(Y^2)$?

Comment: If only using your displayed formula, would also need $E((X+Y)^2)$ it seems.

Comment: So any other ways to find E(XY)?

Comment: Do you know anything else about $X,Y$, for example if they belong to a specific family of random variables?

Comment: I don't know of other ways, but am not an expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$, $Y$ be uniformly distributed random variables, over $[0;1]$, so $\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E(Y)=\tfrac 12$ and $\mathsf E(X^2)=\mathsf E(Y^2)=\tfrac 13$.

Consider the following cases.

- $X,Y$ are independent.  So $\mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y)=0$, because they are uncorrelated.$$\text{Case 1: }\mathsf E(XY)=\tfrac 14$$
- $X=Y$ almost surely.  So $\tfrac{\mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y)}{\sqrt{(\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2)(\mathsf E(Y^2)-\mathsf E(Y)^2)}}=1$.$$\text{Case 2: }\mathsf E(XY)=\tfrac 13$$
- $X=1-Y$ almost surely.  So $\tfrac{\mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y)}{\sqrt{(\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2)(\mathsf E(Y^2)-\mathsf E(Y)^2)}}=-1$.$$\text{Case 3: }\mathsf E(XY)=\tfrac 16$$

Thus the four expectations: $\mathsf E(X),\mathsf E(Y),\mathsf E(X^2),$ and $\mathsf E(Y^2)$, are not sufficient to determine what $\mathsf E(XY)$ will be.   You also need to know how they are correlated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation!

Comment: If we also have $X$ have Poisson distribution, with $E(X)=3$, and  $var(Y\vert X=x)=\dfrac{x+1}{3}$, $E(Y\vert X=x)=\dfrac{x}{2}$. Can we find $E(XY)$?

Comment: Yes. That will give you the covariance, and variance of $Y$.$$\begin{align}\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y)&=\mathsf E(X\,\mathsf E(Y\mid X))-\mathsf E(X)\,\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))\\[2ex] \mathsf{Var}(Y)&=\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}(Y\mid X))+\mathsf{Var}(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much Graham Kemp! I have found the answer of E(XY)=6.

Comment: Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X=Y$ and that $X$ is half the time $1$ and half the time $-1$.  Then $E(X)=E(Y)=0$ and $E(X^2)=E(Y^2)=1$.  Also $E(XY)=1$.

Now replace $Y$  with $-X$.  You haven't changed any of $E(X),E(Y),E(X^2)$ or $E(Y^2)$, but you've changed $E(XY)$ from $1$ to $-1$.

So $E(XY)$ is not determined by the other four.

Comment: Thank you very much..